# Why do I get this error Module 'magento/framework' is not correctly registered

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento2 website running on php 7.1 and Marian DB 10. After upgrade from Magento 2.2.3. to Magento 2.2.4  I get the error message "Module 'magento/framework' is not correctly registered" in the admin dashboard as seen in the screenshot below. How do I fix this?

Screenshot Module https://i.stack.imgur.com/w75sx.jpg